# Rewrite rule in widfly 8 undertow-handlers.conf

Tags: wildfly, undertow

I want to rewrite all url's in wildlfy 8 like this

```
url/home/anything  to URL/home/index.php?q=anything
```

How can i write this in an undertow-handlers config file.

Right now my rule is like this , but this is not working.

```
regex['^/home/(.*)$'] -> rewrite['/home/index.php?q=${0}']
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undertow Rewrite has some issue in wildfly 8. Rewrite is not passing get variables directly in the url like
`regex['/home/(.*)$'] -> rewrite['/home/index.php?gender=men']`,

instead it has to pass as shown below

`set[attribute='%{q,gender}', value='men'];`